# Xamarin.forms. Android: Button look on button image

Tags: android, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, imagebutton

I am making an app for Android and iOS. As far as I understand there is not possible to set a border on imagebuttons on Android. It is possible on iOS.

When I make a imagebutton it does not look like a button on Android. I cannot find a way to give it a button look. I can only find it on buttons with text.

See images for better understanding.

Anyone can help?

This is my code (new to Xamarin and xaml so it is probably not "good looking" code)

```
    <Label  Text="Velg betalingsmetode:"
    TextColor="#002C6C"
    FontSize="Medium"
    VerticalOptions="Center"
    HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

    <Button x:Name="MobilePayButton"
    HeightRequest="100"
    WidthRequest="130"
    HorizontalOptions="Center"
    VerticalOptions="Center"
    BackgroundColor="White"
    BorderColor="#002C6C"
    BorderWidth="2"
    Clicked="ToPayConfirmationPage">

        <Button.Image>
            <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource"
            Android="pay_MobilePaylogo2.png"
            iOS="Pay_MobilePaylogo2.png"/>
        </Button.Image>

    </Button>
```

[image: Android version][image: iOS version]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a button with border, you need to create a customized button:

1. In PCL project add a custom button:

   ```
   public class ButtonWithBorder:Button
   {
   }
   ```
2. Use it in Xaml:

   ```
   <StackLayout
    VerticalOptions="Center">
      <local:ButtonWithBorder Clicked="ButtonWithBorder_Clicked">
       <local:ButtonWithBorder.Image>
           <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource"
               Android="gluehbirne.png"
               iOS="Pay_MobilePaylogo2.png"/>
       </local:ButtonWithBorder.Image>
       </local:ButtonWithBorder>
   </StackLayout>
   ```
3. In Android project, create a `ButtonRenderer` for our custom button:

   ```
   [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ButtonWithBorder),typeof(ButtonWithBorderRenderer))]
   namespace ButtonWithBorderDemo.Droid
   {
       public class ButtonWithBorderRenderer:ButtonRenderer
       {
           protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Button> e)
           {
               base.OnElementChanged(e);
               Control.Background=ContextCompat.GetDrawable(this.Context, Resource.Drawable.button_bg);

           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. Add a `button_bg.axml` to `Resources\drawable`:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shape="rectangle">
     <corners android:radius="3dp" />
     <stroke android:width="5px" android:color="#000000" />
   </shape>
   ```

And you will get a bordered button in android.